# Correctly combine multiple CSS declarations to one

Tags: css

I have multiple CSS declarations with the same properties. I wish to combine all of these, but I don't know the correct way to do this.

**Example:**

```
#wpcf7-f1000-o1 input[type="submit"] {
background: #7a7979;}

#wpcf7-f2000-o1 input[type="submit"] {
background: #7a7979;}
```

Can these be combined like this? Is this correct?

```
#wpcf7-f1000-o1, #wpcf7-f2000-o1 input[type="submit"] {
background: #7a7979;}
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use multiple IDs for divs in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012513/use-multiple-ids-for-divs-in-css)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012513/use-multiple-ids-for-divs-in-css has the answer !"

Comment: use `#wpcf7-f1000-o1 input[type="submit"], #wpcf7-f2000-o1 input[type="submit"] {
background: #7a7979;}`

Answer (score 4):

```
#wpcf7-f1000-o1 input[type="submit"],
#wpcf7-f2000-o1 input[type="submit"]
{
    background: #7a7979;
}
```

Note the comma, that's important and without it the rules mean something else.